# Remove multiple paths from a json

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to remove multiple path from a json transformer.

So if this is my object - this works:

```
{
  "a": {
      "field1": null,
      "field2": 123
  }
  "b": {
      "b1": {
           "field1": null
      },
      "b2": {
           "field1": null
      }
  }
}
```

So if this is my object - this fails:

```
{
  "a": {
      "field1": null,
      "field2": 123
  }
  "b": {
      "b1": null,
      "b2": {
           "field1": null
      }
  }
}
```

I am trying to remove all fields beside "field2".
So I wrote this:

```
((__ \ "a" \ "field1").json.prune andThen
  (__ \ "b" \ "b1" \ "field1").json.prune andThen
  (__ \ "b" \ "b2" \ "field1").json.prune)
```

I get the following error:

```
(/a/field1/b/b1/field1/b/b2/field1/b2/field1,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))
```

I also tried:

```
((__ \ "a" \ "field1").json.prune and
  (__ \ "b" \ "b1" \ "field1").json.prune and
  (__ \ "b" \ "b2" \ "field1").json.prune) reduce
```

And I get the following 2 errors:

```
(/b/b1/field1/b1/field1,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))
(/b/b2/field1/b2/field2,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))
```

What Am I missing?

Comment: For your example Json object first transformer works fine: `JsSuccess({"a":{"field2":123},"b":{"b1":{},"b2":{}}},/a/field1/b/b1/field1/b/b2/field1)`, second is no valid for this.

Comment: Thanks.. I updated my example - The problem is when b1 or b2 are have null value. @andrey.ladniy

Comment: Your problem is deleting field of null object (b.b1.field1, but b.b1 is null). See in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706086/implementing-google-patch-semantic-with-playframework-2-4-json-transformers how you can check null or omitted property. What is you task where you want delete this properties?